# Non abelian $H^1(G,A)$ problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $G,A$ be groups. We do not assume that $A$ is abelian. For $f,g\in Z^1(G,A)$, we write $f\backsim g$ if there is an $a\in A$ such that $g(x)=a^{-1}f(x)\ ^xa$ (we use the pre-exponential notation here).

(1) Show that this is an equivalence relation.

Let $A$ be a $G$-module. Suppose that $A\triangleleft B$, $C=B/A$ are all $G$-modules with compatible actions which means that $^xa$ for $a\in A$ is the same for actions of $G$ on $A$ and $B$, and if $\pi:B\rightarrow C$ is the canonical map, $\pi(^xb)=\ ^x\pi(b)$ for $b\in B$. If $c\in C^G$, we construct an element of $Z^1(G,A)$ as follows: pick $b\in B$ such that $\pi(b)=c$ and $f(x)=b^{-1}\ ^xb$.

(2) Show that $f(x)\in A$ and that $f$ defines an element of $Z^1(G,A)$.

(3) Show that if $c=\pi (b')$ and $f'$ is the corresponding co-cycle, then $f\backsim f'$.Thus for different choices of $b\in B$, we get the same element $\delta (c)\in H^1(G,A)$.

(4) Show that for $c\in C^G$, $c=\pi (b)$ for some $b\in B^G$ iff $\delta (c)\backsim 1$. In particular if $H^1(G,A)$ is a single point, then $B^G\rightarrow C^G$ is surjective.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What did you try to solve this set of problems?

Comment: I showed part (1), need help with rest of the parts.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we have : $\pi(b^{-1}\ ^xb)=\pi(b^{-1})\pi(\ ^xb)=\pi(b^{-1})\ ^x\pi(b)=\pi(b^{-1})\pi(b)$[as $\pi(b)=c$ and $c\in C^G$]=$e$, hence $f\in Z^1(G,A)$. The rest is not that hard either, now I see what's going on.